# Does URLRewrite on Azure uses persistent cache?

Tags: azure, iis, https, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have added a simple rewrite to Azure Web App

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works fine, but when I do any changes, e.g. remove this snippet, change the redirect to "www.google.com", nothing ever changes (it keeps redirecting to https as before)! The only thing that helps is killing App Service and creating a new one. So it really seems it is some kind of forever cache in there. Is it true and if yes, how can we change the behavior to allow changes to existing rules?

P.S. I have found a similar question for generic IIS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796933/unable-to-remove-a-url-rewrite-from-iis7), but it does not have the answer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is indeed an output cache and it can be turned off:

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Be aware though that this is output cache for the whole application, so it might affect something else. In any case it can be utilized and then commented out to clean the state of url rewrite rules.