# Removing an old redirect in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I can't seem to find an answer but I would like to remove an old redirect from the web config file of an IIS server.

Here is the redirect:

```
<rule name="Redirect Old Returns Page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^returns$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/warranties" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I would now like that /returns page to be available, but when I remove that redirect from the config and restart the application pool it still redirects.
Anyone know what's going on? Never had to remove a redirect before and thought it would be simple.
Thanks

Comment: Oh dammit it was a browser cache issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796933/unable-to-remove-a-url-rewrite-from-iis7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to remove a URL rewrite from IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796933/unable-to-remove-a-url-rewrite-from-iis7)